# How to create a window that blocks the parent in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have an order form page within the program I am building in C# with Windows Forms, I want to make it so a user can add items to an order using a separate pop up window which displays a list of products from a which a user can select. Once an item is selected the pop up window closes and an item is added to the order form, the item adding process can be repeated as necessary.

My question is, in addition to showing the window, how would I pass details of the order selected from one form to another?

Comment: Winforms? WPF? What are you using exactly?! Tag properly!

Comment: What is your framework ? Web / WinForms / WCF / Silverlight / Other ? Try sharing some code.

Comment: Even though it's already answered I'm curious as to how this isn't a real question. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @RudiVisser: It's probably because the question is not clear. The title is a different question than the last line in the question.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger That's great; But it's also why we have edit functionality. The question is fairly clear once you get over that small glitch in the title. Fixed now, anyway!

Comment: @Rudi Visser: And that's why we have reopen functionality, to reopen a question after it had been fixed. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dialog.

If you call [`.ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) on a `Form`, it will block until the form is closed.

This means you can do something like the following:

```
// la la normal code
var itemSelect = new ItemSelectionForm();
itemSelect.ShowDialog();
// Check that they have selected something
if (itemSelect.ItemList.SelectedItem != null)
{
    // Item adding code
    // ...
    // Use itemSelect.ItemList.SelectedItem as the selected item from the popup form
}
```

Comment: That worked great thanks. For future reference how would I access string data stored in text boxes from another windows form, would it be using itemSelect.textBox1.Value?

Comment: The same way you do in any normal form, use `.Text`.